# Null geodesic in Rindler spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, geodesics

Having the Rindler metric given as

$$ g_{\mu \nu} = e^{2 a \xi} (-d\tau^2+d\xi^2) \quad (1) $$

I would like to calculate the trajectory of a light beam in the coordinates $\tau$ and $\xi$. There would be an easy (but not so mathematically sound I think) way of doing it:

saying $ds^2=0$ so $d\tau= \pm d\xi$. So with initial condition $\xi=0$ and $\tau=0$ if the light beam goes towards negative $\tau$ then $\tau=-\xi$.

But my problem is with the statement $ds^2=0$. Since $ds^2$ is a tensor, a map from V to R. So it would make sense saying $ ds^2(u^{\mu }, u^{\nu})=0$. Meaning

$$ g_{\mu \nu} u^{\mu } u^{\nu} =0 \quad (2)$$

with $u^{\mu }= \frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}$ and $x^{\mu}(\lambda)$ is the trajectory of the light beam with $\lambda$ the parameterization.

But from here I can't seem to get back to the previous result.
Trying to solve $(2)$ I seem to get:

$$\tau=\lambda c_1$$
$$\xi= \lambda c_2$$

therefore $\xi=\tau c_2/c_1$ and I tried to use: $u^{\mu } u^{\nu} g_{\mu \nu} = -1 $ but it lead me to:

$$\xi = \tau \frac{1}{1+\frac{e^{-a \xi}}{c_2}}$$

Am I missing another constraint somewhere?

Comment: Maybe your mistake is to consider $ds^2$ as a tensor. $ds^2=g_{\mu \nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ is a line element whereas $ds^2=g_{\mu \nu}dx^\mu \otimes dx^\nu$ is the metric 2-form.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux No, the first is a widely used short hand for the symmetric tensor product of 1-forms, and is there for still a tensor.

Comment: I know it is widely used but $ds^2$ is a line element when you consider $g_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu$ as a measure, and is a 2-form when you consider $dx^\mu$ as a vector-valued 1-form. The former is why you can define an action $S=\int_{\mathbb{R}} ds$.

Comment: I think I actually made a mistake in the second derivation. I will modify the answer as soon as I'll be through with the computation.

Comment: I would agree with @mmeent but then why can we define the action as JeanbaptisteRoux wrote?

Comment: Any new comment on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ g_{\mu \nu} u^{\mu } u^{\nu} =0 \quad (2)$$

gives

$$e^{2 a \xi} \left(-\left(\frac{d\tau}{d\lambda}\right)^2+\left(\frac{d\xi}{d\lambda}\right)^2\right)= 0$$

which implies

$$\frac{d\tau}{d\lambda}  = \pm \frac{d\xi}{d\lambda}$$

or by chain rule

$$\frac{d\xi}{d\tau}  = \pm 1$$

i.e.

$$\xi = \pm\tau + c$$

as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your second derivation leads to the solution with
$$
g_{\mu \nu} u^{\mu} u^{\nu}=0
$$
but is a mistake use $ g_{\mu \nu} u^{\mu} u^{\nu}=-1$ because is only valid for massive particles.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake in the computation. But why is the second equation wrong in this context?

Comment: Your second equation is only valid for massive particles, in the proof you make differentiation respect to $d \tau$  but for light $d \tau=0$

Comment: True, silly question, thanks.